# Why windows boost thread priority dynamically?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I was reading Windows via C/C++. In this book, the author has said:

> The system determines the thread's priority level by combining a
> thread's relative priority with the priority class of the thread's
> process. This is sometimes referred to as the thread's base priority
> level. Occasionally, the system boosts the priority level of a
> thread—usually in response to some I/O event such as a window message
> or a disk read.
>
> For example, a thread with a normal thread priority in a high-priority
> class process has a base priority level of 13. If the user presses a
> key, the system places a WM_KEYDOWN message in the thread's queue.
> Because a message has appeared in the thread's queue, the thread is
> schedulable. In addition, the keyboard device driver can tell the
> system to temporarily boost the thread's level. So the thread might be
> boosted by 2 and have a current priority level of 15.

So my question is, why we need this mechanism in Windows OS? What will happen if this mechanism has gone?

Comment: Starvation due to priority inversion.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_boosting

Comment: Specifically, let's say a high priority thread is executing, but periodically checks to see if low priority thread has released a resource, at which point the high-priority thread would stop what it's doing.  The low-priority thread never gets a chance to run, to finish up and release the resource that the high-priority thread needs to continue.  With random boosting, the lower priority thread gets some non-zero amount of time to execute (even though it's lower priority) just in case what it does is necessary to alter the course of the higher priority thread.